# NetSuite Scheduled Script->Create Record Error(SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT)

Tags: netsuite

I'm creating a Scheduled SuiteScript in Netsuite that uses the 2.0 version of the API.

I want to create record,but some errors have occurred.

The script is:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 *@author Sheldor Qu
 *@description  此脚本用于每天定时更新采购价格税率维护表
 *@version V1.0.0
 */
define(['N/record'], function (record) {

    function execute(context) {
        try {
            var customTaskRecord = record.create({
                type: 'customrecord_tp_dev_task',
                isDynamic: true,
            });
            log.debug('new customTaskRecord', customTaskRecord);
        } catch (error) {
            log.debug('error', error);
        }
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    }
});
```

[image]

The error message is:

```
{
    "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
    "name": "SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "task.checkStatus: Missing a required argument: options.taskId",
    "stack": [
        "createError(N/error)",
        "execute(/SuiteScripts/Scheduled Script/TP_SS_PurchasePriceUpdDaily.js:12)"
    ],
    "cause": {
        "type": "internal error",
        "code": "SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT",
        "details": "task.checkStatus: Missing a required argument: options.taskId",
        "userEvent": null,
        "stackTrace": [
            "createError(N/error)",
            "execute(/SuiteScripts/Scheduled Script/TP_SS_PurchasePriceUpdDaily.js:12)"
        ],
        "notifyOff": false
    },
    "id": "",
    "notifyOff": false,
    "userFacing": false
}
```

[image]

I don't know why,please help me.

Comment: Can you number the lines of your script, or indicate which line is line #24 in NetSuite?

Comment: line#24 is:var customTaskRecord = record.create({

Comment: I found the reason, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the error from another script trying to check the status of a task.

```
var taskStatus = task.checkStatus(taskId);
```

but taskId is null or undefined or missing.
Make sure that script sets a variable when submitting the task that you can use as your task id.

```
var taskId = scriptTask.submit();
```

Comment: The strange thing is that I didn't use other scripts.

Comment: Look for a user event script deployed beforeLoad on your custom record type. You would receive any errors the other script throws.

Comment: I checked the script and it is for this reason.Tahank you so much!